# Run 32bit ActiveX control in 64bit Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

I am working on HTML page. Where I have one 32 bit ActiveX Control in the page.
Its working fine on 32 Bit Operating system in Internet Explorer (10,11), but when I try to run in 64 Bit Operating System in Internet Explorer (10,11). Active X Control does not load at all.

I have seen many links but in vain.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load 32-bit ActiveX controls in a 64-bit Internet Explorer instance.

See this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/05/29/q-a-64-bit-internet-explorer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use the 32-bit Internet Explorer from C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer